# PHP parser with button "Show more"

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse links from site by `file_get_contents();`, but problem that some elements how i understand are loading by ajax, after clicking on button `Show more 20`, for example if i get HTML content (Ctrl + U [chrome]), i have only 20 records, and after clicking on button i get else 20 records, but is it real to take all by PHP ? Or maybe there is other way to do it ?

I thought that it's real to do by JavaScript, but it's erroneously cause all the same i use `file_get_content();` default/standart code.

Here is an example: http://msk.gorko.ru/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0/
On the end of page, there is button `"Показать еще 20 ведущих"`.

Comment: What you are trying to do is I think lazy loading, Try to make ajax call and get other 20 records and display it on your page

Comment: But how i get content if i load by ajax ? And how it's real to load by ajax if it's typical handler on button click ?
Here is an example, on the end of page button `"Показать еще 20 ведущих"`. 
link: http://msk.gorko.ru/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All user id hidden in #user_ids, first get it, if u use "simplehtmldom", it will be like this:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://msk.gorko.ru/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0/');
$ids = $html->find('#user_ids', 0)->value;
$request = array(
   'http' => array(
     'method' => 'POST',
     'content' => http_build_query(array(
         'ids' => $ids,
         'role_id' => '7',
         'noportfolio' => '0',
         'BITRIX_SECURITY_KEY' => **TAKE FROM COOKIE**
      )),
   )
);

$context = stream_context_create($request);

$json = file_get_html('http://msk.gorko.ru/services/more/', false, $context);
```

Only replace ****TAKE FROM COOKIE****

Comment: Thanks ! Didn't see that hidden id's.